# SharePoint 2013 continous crawl question and incremental

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

SharePoint 2013 Ent with SP1 and September CU

I have question about the GUI when change the crawl to Continuous crawl. When I change the crawl to continuous crawl although the incremental crawl shows None for schedule as shown below:

[image]

I noticed that when I enable continuous crawl, the schedule automatically changes to every 4 hours for the incremental section s shown below:

[image]

I don't know why is that, and does that mean that incremental crawl will happen every 4 hours in addition to continuous crawl, which default do incremental crawls every 15 min.?

Also, I would like to point point even when continuous crawl is select, the drop down menu under **Enable Incremental crawls** are still active and gives you two options. Is this is a confirmed **Bug**?

Answer (score 4):

that is expected behavior, but it does not mean that incremental crawl runs every 4 hours. you have to select between continuous vs incremental.

When you click on Continuous Crawl it disable the Incremental crawl. Continuous crawl automatically run every 15 min( by default).

> Continuous crawls crawl SharePoint sites frequently to help keep
>   search results fresh. Like incremental crawls, a continuous crawl
>   crawls content that was added, changed, or deleted since the last
>   crawl. Unlike an incremental crawl, which starts at a particular time
>   and repeats regularly at specified times after that, a continuous
>   crawl automatically starts at predefined time intervals. The default
>   interval for continuous crawls is every 15 minutes. Continuous crawls
>   help ensure freshness of search results because the search index is
>   kept up to date as the SharePoint content is crawled so frequently.
>   Thus, continuous crawls are especially useful for crawling SharePoint
>   content that is quickly changing.

Read more on this article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219802(v=office.15).aspx on the page read how to disable the continuous crawl.

Comment: Yes, think of continuous crawls as quick, effective, mini incremental crawls. It's like comparing a sports car to 10 go-karts all on one track.

Comment: I want to make sure it is a bug in GUI. I am ware of the articles that you mention, and read it already. Also, I would like to add that when you flip the switch to continuous crawl or when continuous crawl is select the drop down menu is still active and you have two choices: Every 4 hour(s) from 12:00 AM for 14 hour(s)..etc

Comment: I see this as well. However, when I look at my crawl log for my content source, it still has incremental crawls getting kicked off every 4 hours, lasting for several minutes.

Answer (score 2):

What happens is if you set it to "Continious Crawl" is the following:

- Continious Crawls (These are not incrementals) will happen every 15
  Minutes (default)
- In addition to the 15 minute continious crawls,
  every 4 hours incremental crawl will kick off.

You can adjust the continious crawl interval only via powershell - default is 15 minutes.

Source: http://www.hanseatech.com/fresh-search-results-sharepoint/